# Configure a simple JavaScript file based on a value in the Redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

so, I developed an application with RN and Redux, I have a `colors.js` file like that

```
const Colors = {
   mainColorDark: '#E34b3d',
   mainColor: '#e3596d',
   mainColorLight: '#F0965C',
}

export default Colors;
```

The client has requested to add another type of user with a different color code. I store the code type in the global Redux store under the value 'userCode: '0' or '1'. For user '0', the color codes remain unchanged; however, I need to add a condition or a switch case in the '`colors.js`' file to modify the color codes based on the 'userCode'. If I were to do it differently, I would have to modify dozens of files, which I want to avoid.

For a simple component, I use `Colors` object from `colors.js` like this:

```
import Colors from '../../../Utilities/Colors/Colors';
export default Styles = StyleSheet.create({

  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: Colors.mainBackgroud,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  NBRcompText: {
    fontSize: hp('3%'),
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: Colors.maiColors,
  },
...
});
```

and for userCode I call it simply like that:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
...
export const TransItem = ({ TransItem, selectItem, goToScanScreen }) => {
  const whichUser = useSelector(state => state.userType.userCode)
...
    return (
      <View style={[Styles.ringContainer, { backgroundColor: color }]}>
        // use the userCode here for example
      </View>
    )
  }
```

so how to access userCode in `colors.js`, bearing in mind that this is not a React component?

Comment: Where is `Colors` used/read/referenced? Where/how are you reading the `userCode` value from the store? Please [edit] to clarify what you are trying to do and the relevant code you are trying to do it with. See [mcve].

Comment: Maybe instead of trying to read a value from the store when exporting this `Colors` object you read both `Colors` and `userCode` somewhere at runtime and compute a new merged colors object with the values you require.

Comment: @DrewReese you ca explain more please ? I have a lot of import Colors from .... in my app, I want to avoid changing these imports

Comment: In `TransItem` is `color` effectively `NBRcompText.color`?  What I mean is, in the React code where you are selecting `userCode` from the store, use that to compute a merged color object that has the color key/values you need.

Comment: @DrewReese I uderstand ow but I have sooo many files to edit if I do it like that, I want to change only colors.js if it possible before use this solution

Comment: Are you opposed to converting `Colors` into a function that can be called at runtime that returns the color object/values? Or `Styles`? Where and how is `Styles` used? Is it computed and exported only once?

Comment: btw, it's react native not reactJs app

Answer (score 1):

I suggest converting `Colors` and `Styles` to functions that are called at runtime that return the appropriate computed values after accessing the current Redux store value.

Example:

```js
import store from '../path/to/store';

const defaultColors = {
  mainColorDark: '#E34b3d',
  mainColor: '#e3596d',
  mainColorLight: '#F0965C',
};

const getColors = () => {
  const state = store.getState();
  const { userCode } = state.userType;

  return {
    ...defaultColors,
    ...userCode ? {
      mainColorDark: '#....',
      mainColor: '#....',
      mainColorLight: '#....',
      ....,
    } : {},
  };
};

export default getColors;
```

```js
import getColors from '../../../Utilities/Colors/Colors';

export default getStyles = () => StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: getColors().mainBackgroud,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  NBRcompText: {
    fontSize: hp('3%'),
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: getColors().maiColors,
  },
  ...
});
```

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import getStyles from '../path/to/Styles.js';

...
export const TransItem = ({ TransItem, selectItem, goToScanScreen }) => {
  const styles = getStyles();

  const whichUser = useSelector(state => state.userType.userCode);

  const { color } = styles.NBRcompText;

  ...

  return (
    <View style={[Styles.ringContainer, { backgroundColor: color }]}>
      // use the userCode here for example
    </View>
  )
};
```

Comment: I like your way too. it seems it's purer. To be honest, I think he should change his mindset. I think he shouldn't reach this point to have a segregated file of styles. The ReactJs team brought the hooks exactly to avoid these kinds of things. He should use component definitions and hooks inside their bodies. Really there is no need to segregate styles. A repetitive style or styles means there needs to be written segregated components and hooks.

Comment: @AmerllicA FWIW that's a React-Native pattern. They define the React component, and in the same file define a local `Styles` object using `Stylesheet.create`. You can create "global" stylesheets as well though. When I first moved from RN to pure React I tried to keep this pattern and did struggle a bit to adapt to normal web development (CSS/css-in-js/etc).

Comment: Dear @DrewReese, You are right, I can completely understand what you meant. But still, there are a couple of ways to have a consistent pattern between the web and RN without struggles like using `Linaria` or using `tailwindcss` and etc.

Comment: it doest throw any error but when I change userCode value from '0' to '1' or to '2' colors doesn't change

Comment: @zedArt When the Redux store is updated this `TransItem` component should be triggered to be rerendered, and when it does the function body calls `getStyles` which should recompute its return value. If you are still struggling would it be possible for you to create a ***running*** [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/) of your app that we could inspect live?

Comment: @DrewReese this is the best solution for my question so I will validate it for other visitors, but since anyway I have to change a lot of files, I will rather use another method.

Comment: @AmerllicA I know that is not the good way but I was looking for the solution that will cost me the least amount of time

Comment: @zedArt I think maybe you aren't thinking far enough ahead... small code change now might necessarily equal writing more code to use in the long run.... or take a step back and really think about your app code's needs and spend more time now refactoring to use a better pattern which might equal less code and effort in the long run. I'm a lazy programmer, so it's my personal philosophy to work really hard once, now, so I can be lazy going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you are doing is not in the ReactJs standard mindset. *Segregating styles from the components*! This is not a good way, You should build a good custom hook to call it inside the other hooks or function components to access what you want.

I mean your `colors.js` is out of the ReactJs concept. I highly recommend you do a simple refactor of what you have done so far.

**But** if you still think your way is correct try to use [`Zustand`](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand) to make your `userCode` hook. Then Zustand will give you this chance to have access to your data outside of the ReactJs tree. It does mean even inside your `colors.js` file you can have access to it.

**HINT**: *Zustand works on both Web and React Native environments.*

### Follow the example to get what I meant:

```js
// userCode.js file

import { create } from 'zustand'

const userCode = create((set) => {
   ~~~ Bla Bla Bla
   
   return { /* object of state */ };
})
```

Then inside your `colors.js` file:

```js
// colors.js file

import Colors from '../../../Utilities/Colors/Colors';

console.log(userCode.getState());
// The above line can give you the state of userCode hook

export default Styles = StyleSheet.create({

  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: Colors.mainBackgroud,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  NBRcompText: {
    fontSize: hp('3%'),
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: Colors.maiColors,
  },
...
});
```